# Value from <select> options to a span CSS class

Tags: jquery, css, select, text, drop-down-menu

I've been trying to get this working for a few days now.. flabbergasted. I'm not an expert on JavaScript/jQuery AT ALL, so go easy, haha. ;-)

I have a dropdown with 9 values. I also have a span with a class set to 'option0'. The dropdown obviously has values ranging from 1 to 9. I want to change the class of the span when the dropdown is changed as well. If the dropdown is used and option 5 is selected, I want the span to have class 'option5'.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Thanks for reading, hope to hear from you guys soon. c:

Comment: Did any of these answers help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('select').change(function(){
   var val = $(this).val();
   alert(val);
   $('span').removeAttr('class').addClass('option' + val);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SAy7W/1/

Comment: What happens when you choose third option and then fifth option? :)

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! (I had to make some adjustments, but it works just fine now!)

Answer (score 2):

```
<select id="your_select">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
  <option>Option 5</option>
  <option>Option 6</option>
  <option>Option 7</option>
  <option>Option 8</option>
  <option>Option 9</option>
</select>
<span id="slave" class="option0">option0</span>
​

$('#your_select').on('change', function() {
    var value = $('option:selected', this).text().replace(/Option\s/, '');
    $('#slave').removeClass().addClass('option' + value).text('option' + value)
});​
```

**[Working Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/CuNcy/1/)**

If you `select` is like following:

```
<select id="your_select">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
  <option value="option6">Option 6</option>
  <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
  <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
  <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
</select>
<span id="slave" class="option0">option0</span>
```

Then

```
$('#your_select').on('change', function() {
    var value = this.value;
    $('#slave').removeClass().addClass(value).text(value)
});​
```

**[Working Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Affrq/3/)**

Comment: Might as well use `var value = this.selectedIndex/* + 1*/;` :)

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
​<select id="master">
    <option>Content 1</option>
    <option>Content 2</option>
    <option>Content 3</option>
    <option>Content 4</option>
    <option>Content 5</option>
    <option>Content 6</option>
    <option>Content 7</option>
</select>
​<span id="slave">option0</span>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

jQuery:

```
​$('#master').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $('#slave').removeClass().addClass('option' + selected);
});​​​
```

CSS:

```
​.option​0 {
    background-color: red;
}
.option1 {
    background-color: green;
}
.option2 {
    background-color: brown;
}
.option3 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.option4 {
    background-color: blue;
}

...
```

See a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JAhRh/1/)

Alternatively, if you want to have any content between the option tags, apply a custom attribute 'data-position' and use this jQuery:

```
$('#master').change(function() {
    var selected = $('#master option:selected').attr('data-position');
    alert(selected);
    $('#slave').removeClass().addClass('option' + selected);
});​
```

See an updated live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JAhRh/2/)